# GET fails on background script, chrome app -

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, get

**Background script (background-services.js)**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
        "use strict";
        if (message.request === "retrieve_url") {
            alert("Received file retrieval demand for file " + message.fileName);
            var url = chrome.extension.getUrl(message.fileName); 
            alert("url calculated: " + url);
         }
    }
);
```

**Content script (google-translate.js)**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    request: "retrieve_url",
    fileName: "templates/toast.html"
});
```

**Manifest**

```
...
"permissions": [
    "*://translate.google.com/*"
],
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "src/common/jquery-2.1.3.min.js",
        "src/background/background-services.js"
    ]
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://translate.google.com/*"],
        "js": ["src/common/jquery-2.1.3.min.js", "src/scripts/google-translate.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
],
"web_accessible_resources": ["templates/toast.html"]
```

I get the alert about the received request for file retrieval but then nothing happens nor is logged to the console nor to the Extension Developer Tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = chrome.extension.getUrl(message.fileName);
```

The correct form is `var url = chrome.extension.getURL(message.fileName);`

Coding overheating, sometimes.

Comment: Well. Actually, this function is directly available in content scripts as `chrome.runtime.getURL()`